# Apply affine transformation on Cesium rendered frame

Tags: graphics, camera, registration, affinetransform, cesiumjs

I have an image which was taken from an airplane. I know the airplane position when the picture hasbeen taken (lat lon height, heading pitch yaw and camera fov).
Suppose I would like Cesium to show the earth exactly like the image was taken. I can do it by:

1. Set Cesium container div to have same width/height as in the image.
2. Set camera.frustum.fov to appropriate values.
3. Use camera.setView with positionCartographic and angles.

The registration data of it are not accurate, thus the image has additional data produced by accurate registrator (**Edit3:** notice that I don't ask about such registrator, I already have the registrator output). The data is a fixing formula that should be applied on the image. The formula is represented as an affine matrix that should be applied on the image (2d, 3x3 matrix in which the last line is 0 0 1).

To get this fix on Cesium, I should apply something similar to the affine transformation on Cesium camera. What is the best way to do that?

**Edit2:** The way I suggested below will not work. I need to find a way to apply the affine transformation **after** any world-to-screen calculation and **before** any screen-to-world calculation is done. This is a purely technical question in Cesium core. How should I do that? I'm afraid that such transformation is performed in many places in the code...

[
For whom it may concern, there are some reasons that the way I deletted below will not work. Here is some intuitive explanations, a mathematical explanation follows:

1. The affine transformation translation has no equivalent operation that can be applied on the camera. Moving the camera by moveLeft is not equivalent, for example if I have a mountain on the left side of the scane it will hide larger area when I move the camera to the right and that doesn't happen in affine transformation applied on the rendered frame. Using rotateLeft is also not equivalent - try to draw it in 3D with the near and far planes of the camera and you will understand that easily.
2. The solution ignores the shearing components of the matrix. Shearing can really be decomposed to rotate-scale-rotate as I've done, but scaling after rotate is not equivalent to just change the fov if the horizontal and vertical fov are not equal - which is exactly what is required to perform shearing.

More mathematical intuition for that is: General affine 2x2 transformation which applied on the frame is equivalent (I think) to apply some transformation on the 4x4 matrix transformation of the camera, *but* general matrix cannot be converted to a camera parameters. Camera model has 8 freedom degrees (3 position's coordinates, 3 euler angles and 1 or 2 fov, depends on if aspect ratio freedom exists), but 3d to 2d perspective transformation has 12 components (11 freedom degrees because w can be normalized).
]

<s>I thought first to decomposite the matrix into 4 matrices: translation, rotate, scale and another rotate. Assuming I know how to do that, I should apply the four matrices on the camera.</s>

- Applying the rotate transformations is easily done by twistLeft.
- Applying the translation is trickier, <s>I can move the camera by moveLeft and moveUp, but I don't know what amount should I pass to move in a given amount of pixels? (the matrix is given in terms of the image pixels which may be easily transformed into screen pixels</s> (**Edit:** I think I should use rotateUp and rotateLeft to get the effect of affine translation, but I'm not sure if it equivalent to the translation. moveLeft and moveUp that were suggested in deletted suggestion because translation of camera is not equivalent to translation of the image. For example if I have a mountain on the left side of the scane it will hide larger area when I move the camera to the right. This example demonstrates why tthe camera cannot move).
- I'm not sure how to apply a scale transformation. <s>I thought about moving the camera forward or reduce the fov, but I wasn't sure if: a. Is it equivalent to a linear scale on the image? b. What amount should I pass to move or how to calculate the new fov?</s> (**Edit:** I should reduce the fov. Moving the camera is wrong as was mentioned in the previous bullet about translation).

Finally if I succeed all the above I would like to handle cases in which the horizontal scale and vertical scale are not equal. Is it possible in Cesium?

Honestly I would prefer to just multiply the affine transformation with the internal camera matrix, but I couldn't find such functionality in the API. Anyway I also consider to change Cesium source code but this is the least prefered option now.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that what are you are asking is orthorectification so it can not be easily done in Cesium. It is a complex task and here is the discussion on sister site where you can learn more. Also try asking this question there.

https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/9334/free-gis-software-that-can-orthorectify

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Maybe the question was misleading - Orthorectification was already done and I have the affine matrix produced in that process. I just need to view it correctly in Cesium.